# Can additional items be added to the params array in the routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My routing involves the subdomain of the site and although I can capture this into a variable in the application controller I prefer to do so in the routing file so that the translation of the URL into parameters all happens in the same place.

My question is whether I can manually append a variable to the `params` array in the `routes.rb` file

**i.e. `routes.rb`:**

```
resources users do
  resources profiles do
  end
end

@params[:organisation] = request.host
```

There is no direct access to `params` and `@params` doesn't work either - is there any other access method?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible via the `defaults` option

From the docs:

```
# Sets params[:format] to 'jpg' by default
match 'path' => 'c#a', :defaults => { :format => 'jpg' }
```

[resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) takes the same options as [match](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-match), plus some additional ones.